# Ubuntu 18.04 /usr/bin/curl changed overnight

Tags: ubuntu

I've recently installed Wazuh across my estate and I noticed that the curl binary changed for all my servers at roughly the same time.

I don't believe that anybody performed an upgrade at that time.

There is nothing in my syslog around that time that could suggest a reason for this to happen.

What could some of the reasons be for a single binary file to change its checksum?

Is this something peculiar to curl?

Comment: You "don't believe" there was an upgrade, but did you crosscheck the curl versions against the curl releases, for example? It also does not have to be logged in syslog.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that.  I see that there was a curl release on September 11th so maybe an upgrade did manage to run somehow.  Ah, and it was a security upgrade which would have been run by unattended-upgrades.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

On my 18.04 servers libcurl was updated yesterday morning during the automatic installation of security updates.

```
Start-Date: 2019-09-12  06:37:07
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7, 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8)
End-Date: 2019-09-12  06:37:07

Start-Date: 2019-09-12  06:37:10
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libcurl4:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7, 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8)
End-Date: 2019-09-12  06:37:10
```

I would assume that updates for curl were also provided at that time.